# problema al responder al proximo cliente en lista cuando el cliente se desconecta ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket

Tengo un problema en mi servidor, ya que intento que al momento de que un cliente se desconecte en automatico pase ala siguiente peticion de la lista y le responda al clliente que ralizo la peticion:

**Ejemplo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Problema:**

El problema radica en que el servidor permanece conectado al cliente que se desconecto y no hace el cambio al nuevo cliente en lista; dando un resultado como esto:

```
Mensaje: hola soy el cliente 1
Para cllinte 1 >: Hola soy el cliente 2  #Cliente 1 se desconecta y se imprime el proximo mensaje en cola
                  #Aqui deneria de conectarse ahora con cliente 2 pero no lo hace
```

**Ejemplo:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el ejmplo anterior despues de cerrar la conexion con el cliente1 deberia de responder al cliente2 pero pues no funciona

Este es el codigo:

**servidor.py**

```
import socket
import threading

class Hilo1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,Funcion,Funcion2,cliente,direccion):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.Funcion = Funcion
        self.Funcion2 = Funcion2
        self.Cliente = cliente
        self.Direccion = direccion

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.Funcion(self.Cliente,self.Direccion)
        except ConnectionResetError:
            self.Funcion2(self.Cliente)


class Servidor_C():
    def __init__(self):

        self.ListaUsuarios = []
        self.ListaMensajes = []

        self.Escucha()

    def EliminarUsuario(self,cliente):
        self.ListaUsuarios.remove(cliente)
        for elemento in self.ListaMensajes:
            if elemento[1] == cliente:
                self.ListaMensajes.remove(elemento)
                self.LeerMensaje()

    def LeerMensaje(self):
        while self.ListaMensajes:
            for i,mensaje in enumerate(self.ListaMensajes):
                print(mensaje[0])
                resuesta = input("> ")
                print("\n",mensaje[1],"--","nuevo conexion")
                mensaje[1].sendall(resuesta.encode())
                self.ListaMensajes.remove(self.ListaMensajes[i])


    def RecibirMensaje(self,cliente,direccion):
        while True:
            mensaje = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
            self.ListaMensajes.append([mensaje,cliente,direccion])
            if len(self.ListaMensajes) == 1:
                threading.Thread(target=self.LeerMensaje).start()

    def Escucha(self):
        servidor = socket.socket()
        conexion = ("192.168.1.78",500)

        servidor.bind(conexion)
        servidor.listen(2)

        while True:
            cliente,direccion = servidor.accept()
            self.ListaUsuarios.append(cliente)
            Hilo1(self.RecibirMensaje,self.EliminarUsuario,cliente,direccion).start()

Servidor_C()
```

**cliente.py**

```
import socket

conexion = ("Dell",500)
cliente = socket.socket()
cliente.connect(conexion)

while True:
    linea = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(linea.encode())
    respuesta = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    print(respuesta)
cliente.close()
```